# [zabbix]Why could not acquire the data from zabbix agent machine?

Tags: zabbix

When I use command `zabbix_agentd -t "proc.num[sshd]"`

in zabbix agent machine,it returns `proc.num[sshd]                                [u|3]`

However, when I user command `zabbix_get -k zabbix_agent IP -k proc.num[sshd]`

in zabbix server machine,it returns `0`

the version of zabbix is 1.8.

Comment: check the zabbix server ip is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

One of the common issues in such cases might be permissions: you might be running the first command under root, whereas in the second case the agent is running as a non-root user and is thus in a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

Get in to the server to be monitored check the agent is running or not

Check your agent config file

```
>vim /etc/zabbix/zabbix-agent.conf
>server ip : your ip of zabbix server
```

Then save the file and restart the zabbix agent

> sudo service zabbix-agent restart

Go to Zabbix dashboard and Monitoring > Latest data > select host > Apply